# Trying to use two <div> inside a <li>, which are supposed to run a script. [Not sure if it's possible]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure if what i am trying to do is going to work, but i want to insert inside a li two div that will run some script for some links that are inside them. A bit confusing, i know, i cant explain it in a better way.

Take a look at my code:

***Inside the body of HTML***

```
<ul>

   <li> TEST </li>
   <li> TEST 2
     <ul>
       <li>  
           <div id="dock2" class="dock">
             <div class="dock-container2" style="left: 760px; width: 400px;">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="dock-item2" href="#" style="width: 40px; left: 0px;"><span style="display: none;">Home</span><img alt="home" src="Inc/Images/dock/home.png"/></a> </li>
                  <li><a class="dock-item2" href="#" style="width: 40px; left: 40px;"><span style="display: none;">Contact</span><img alt="contact" src="Inc/Images/dock/email.png"/></a></li>
                  <li><a class="dock-item2" href="#" style="width: 40px; left: 80px;"><span style="display: none;">Portfolio</span><img alt="portfolio" src="Inc/Images/dock/portfolio.png"/></a></li>
                  <li><a class="dock-item2" href="#" style="width: 40px; left: 120px;"><span style="display: none;">Music</span><img alt="music" src="Inc/Images/dock/music.png"/></a></li>
                  <li><a class="dock-item2" href="#" style="width: 40px; left: 160px;"><span style="display: none;">Video</span><img alt="video" src="Inc/Images/dock/video.png"/></a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
       <li> TEST 3 </li>
</ul>
```

***The script that is running inside the div, also in the body of HTML***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dock2').Fisheye({
   maxWidth: 60,
   items: 'a',
   itemsText: 'span',
   container: '.dock-container2',
   itemWidth: 40,
   proximity: 80,
   alignment : 'left',
   valign: 'bottom',
   halign : 'center'
   }
   )
   }
   );
</script>
```

***And finally the CSS***

```
.dock {

    position: relative; 

    height: 50px; 

    text-align: center;

}

.dock-container {

    position: absolute;

    height: 50px;

    background:url(Inc/Images/dock/dock-bg2.gif);

    padding-left: 20px;

}

a.dock-item {

    display: block;

    width: 40px;

    color: #000;

    position: absolute;

    top: 0px;

    text-align: center;

    text-decoration: none;

    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

.dock-item img {

    border: none; 

    margin: 5px 10px 0px; 

    width: 100%; 

}

.dock-item span {

    display: none; 

    padding-left: 20px;

}



/* dock2 - bottom */

#dock2 {

    width: 100%;

    bottom: 0px;

    position: absolute;

    left: 0px;

}

.dock-container2 {

    position: absolute;

    height: 50px;

    background:url(Inc/Images/dock/dock-bg.gif);

    padding-left: 20px;

}

a.dock-item2 {

    display: block; 

    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    width: 40px; 

    color: #000; 

    bottom: 0px; 

    position: absolute;

    text-align: center;

    text-decoration: none;

}

.dock-item2 span {

    display: none;

    padding-left: 20px;

}

.dock-item2 img {

    border: none; 

    margin: 5px 10px 0px; 

    width: 100%; 

}
```

So what i am actually trying to do, is put inside a list a dock that acts like OS X, moving the mouse over the icons making them to zoom, though with the above code the zoom doesn't work.

If i move the part of the dock outside the list and put it somewhere in the body, everything works as it should, but inside the list no animation.

I am not sure at all if this is possible, having an animation running inside a li, any help is really appreciated.

P.S I also have an another CSS that is about the li style, but i thing its irrelevant to the question so i didn't include it.

Edit: Added it on **jsfiddle**.  Link: **http://jsfiddle.net/UTw84/3/**

The dock i am trying to make is this one: **http://www.ndesign-studio.com/demo/css-dock-menu/css-dock.html**

**Note:** on jsfiddle it doesn't show the icons, probably because there is no path for them.

**Edit 2:** The problem was/is with CSS. i made some changes and its working better now. http://jsfiddle.net/UTw84/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UTw84/4/

Is this what you want ?

I just added something to your CSS selector :

```
#main-list ul li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The last CSS selector was overriding the :hover selector.

EDIT :

I see.

http://jsfiddle.net/UTw84/5/

It works here but when you want to put a "left" property to the main-dock, it breaks everything.

Comment: If you check the link with the dock you will see how the effect should be used. Making a zoom in, in the icons.

http://www.ndesign-studio.com/demo/css-dock-menu/css-dock.html

Comment: Thanks to your first answer, making some changes in the CSS made it work better. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/UTw84/6/

Comment: In Dreamweaver, where i have all the code, its working much better now, i can see the icons and of course the zoom in when i hover over them.

Comment: i'm glad i could help you a bit